# What is the best way to measure total context switches in a C/C++ application?

Tags: c, linux, performance

This is simple way I am trying to get the resource usage, specially total context switches that happen in the execution of the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int appgetrusage(struct rusage *);
int appgetdiffrusage(struct rusage *, struct rusage *);

int main() {
    struct rusage begin, end;

    appgetrusage(&begin);

/*
* core of the program goes here 
* where lot of system threads are spawned and joined
*
*/

    appgetrusage(&end);
    appgetdiffrusage(&begin, &end);

    return 0;
}


int appgetrusage(struct rusage *usage){
    int who = RUSAGE_SELF;
    struct timeval start, end;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, usage);
    return 1;
}


int appgetdiffrusage(struct rusage *oldr, struct rusage *newr){

    printf("\n");    
    printf("user time (ms): %llu\n",1000 * ((newr->ru_utime).tv_sec - (oldr->ru_utime).tv_sec) + 
            ((newr->ru_utime).tv_usec - (oldr->ru_utime).tv_usec) / 1000);

    printf("system time (ms): %ld\n", 1000 * ((newr->ru_stime).tv_sec - (oldr->ru_stime).tv_sec) + 
            ((newr->ru_stime).tv_usec - (oldr->ru_stime).tv_usec) / 1000);         

    printf("voluntary context switches : %ld\n", newr->ru_nvcsw - oldr->ru_nvcsw);
    printf("involuntary context switches : %ld\n", newr->ru_nivcsw - oldr->ru_nivcsw);

    return 1;
}
```

1. Is this the right approach?
2. Can anybody suggest an alternative? or Corrections? :-)

Comment: Why do you care about context switches? Isn't measure the real and CPU time enough for you?

Comment: Several context switches degrades performance of the system. Involuntary context switches, for example, more in number is always bad. That means there is something terribly wrong in the underlying system or the libraries depending on

Comment: Of course, but what matters is ultimately time.... And context switches depend also of the rest of the system (not only of the application...)....

Comment: I agree! context switches depend on whole system. Since i have an issue with degraded performance of an application. I am interested to know the cause :-) http://stackoverflow.com/q/21777430/815812

Comment: What do you think about the way I am calculating the difference of context switches? Will that do to research on the issue where resource usage is more? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can anybody suggest an alternative?

Use perf (https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Counting_with_perf_stat):

```
perf stat your-program
```

Like this:

```
>perf stat ./my_test 2
Thread 139828421826304:
Thread 139828411336448:
^[[A./my_test: Terminated

 Performance counter stats for './my_test 2':

      74333.536760 task-clock                #    1.999 CPUs utilized
               627 context-switches          #    0.008 K/sec
                26 cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
               282 page-faults               #    0.004 K/sec
      182727508914 cycles                    #    2.458 GHz                     [50.00%]
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-frontend
   <not supported> stalled-cycles-backend
      121168605770 instructions              #    0.66  insns per cycle         [75.00%]
       30262379463 branches                  #  407.116 M/sec                   [74.99%]
           1635031 branch-misses             #    0.01% of all branches         [75.01%]

      37.181359478 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find what each line mean? For example, what does 'task-clock', 'branches' mean? Any man page reference?

Comment: Task-clock - As far as I know it is execution time of all threads in your application if it is multithreaded. So if your applicaton has 2 threads running all the time and it finishes after 10 seconds then task-clock will be around 20 secs (or 20000 msec)

Comment: Ok.. Thanks! I have two apps working on different versions of library. With same number of threads spawned (5k threads). What parameters should I consider to compare the best among them? Is it the branches, or branch-misses, or instructions, or cycles? Any online resource, a detailed man page maybe, you can refer me to?

Comment: As for branches. There are two useful links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820319/why-is-a-cpu-branch-instruction-slow and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Actually I usually start comparing different versions of a library using higher level metrics. For example I send lots of requests so that my application fully utilizes CPU and then measure Req/sec. If then I see that one of them is worse than another I use perf to find where it works worse.

Comment: One more observation! `context-switches` in `perf stat` is the total of "voluntary" and "non-voluntary" context switches made by app. Double checked with output of getrusage().

Answer (score 1):

Systemtap provides excellent facility to profile/debug user space as well as kernel codes.

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/

systemtap script for finding context switches
https://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/chng_cpu.stp

In ARM, user space profiling is not yet available, because of uprobes(https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linux-linaro/+spec/arm-uprobes).  But X86, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You guys already shared the best resources like perf and systemtap, but if anyone just don't want to look into that much depth then sysstat package coming with RHEL6 or kernels 2.6.23 and later have something called pidstat. Use pidstat with `-w` and it will give you total number of voluntary as well as non-voluntary context switches.